# Overiding a list of integers with a new produced list c++ std::List

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I am trying to replace a list of numbers with a new list of numbers produced. The function Sort takes in a list of numbers(**Radix Sort** i think). For example

```
std::list<int> list;
 list contains 2,1;
```

when the function Sort is called the list containing 2 and 1 will be used. Even module goes to list 0 and the odd to list 1. After that i want to overide my list to use the new list. The process keeps going until the divisor(refer to code) is larger then the largest number in my list.Once that is done my list will be sorted.

```
Example list{2,1}
Sort(list)
   divisor=1;
 while (divisor <largest_item_in_list)
    {
      for(go through list and get the number)
        n=(number/1)%2
          if(n==0)
             put into list0
          else
             put into list1

     }
         divisor=divisor*2;
          put list together using splice function from std::List           


       2 gets put into list 0 
       1 gets put into list 1
       since the divisor is still less than the largest int in the list the loop is ran again
        when the loop is ran again the list produced is 
        2 goes into list 1
        1 goes into list 0
        put the list back to the original 
        List is now sorted list= 1,2
```

After the divisor is larger than the largest number in the list we exit the loop
My new list produced is now list= {1,2} and is now sorted.

```
    .

 int getMax(std::list<int> list_Original)
{
int mx = list_Original.front();
for(std::list<int>::iterator i=list_Original.begin();i !=list_Original.end();i++)
{
    if(*i>mx)
    {
        mx=*i;
    }
}

return mx;
}



void Sort(std::list<int> list_Original)
{
int largest_number_in_list=getMax(list_Original);
int divisor=1;
std::list<int> list_0;//Hold even numbers
std::list<int> list_1;//Holds odd Numbers


std::list<int> new_original;//List of integer
new_original=list_Original;




while(divisor<=largest_number_in_list)
{


    for(std::list<int>::iterator i=new_original.begin();i != new_original.end();i++)
        {


            int n=((*i/divisor)%2);

            if(n==0)
            {

                list_0.push_back(*i);


            }
            else
            {

                list_1.push_back(*i);
               // new_original.remove(*i);
            }
           // std::cout<<*i<<"="<<n<<"the divisor is"<<"="<<divisor<<std::endl;





        }

    divisor=2*divisor;

   // new_original=test;

}

new_original.splice(new_original.begin(),list_1);
new_original.splice(new_original.begin(),list_0);



for(std::list<int>::iterator i=new_original.begin();i !=new_original.end();i++)
 {
     std::cout<<*i<<std::endl;

}


 }






int main ()
{

    int array[]={2,1};
 //  int n=sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
     std::list<int> my_list(array,array+2);
   //getMax(my_list);

     Sort(my_list);
     std::cout<<"hi";


  }
```

Comment: You're passing the lists by value everywhere, which means changes made inside the functions won't be reflected in the original list, only in the copy. Change to passing by reference.

Comment: You know that `list_Original` in `Sort` is a separate variable from `my_list` in `main`? So you can do whatever you want to `list_Original`, and it won't affect `my_list`...

Comment: @JonathanPotter  Okay so i should use the original List and pass it by reference correct. Sorry new to c++ okay ill try it out

Comment: Got it working if any1 would like to see the end product let me know :)